# You can be famous but not be a celebrity

Tags: grammar, ambiguity, semantics, conjunction-reduction

This is from a school task:

1. You can be famous but not be a celebrity.

What they mean is:

2. You **can be** famous **without being** a celebrity.

Can some people (depending on prosody?) interpret (1) to mean (3) instead?

3. You **can be** famous but you **cannot be** a celebrity.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be a possible interpretation.

Comment: @Barmar The second instance of *be* in (1) makes the alternate reading in (3) far less likely than the correct reading in (2).  Had it been omitted, that analysis would differ.

Comment: @tchrist I don't agree that the second "be" really changes the analysis. I think (2) is the more likely parse in either case, but (3) is a possible parse.

Comment: +1 to tchrist on the implications of the second **be**.  If you were setting someone's expectations, "You can be on the team but not a starter"  there wouldn't be a second **be**.  "... but you *wouldn't be* a starter" is possible.

Comment: I took it to mean #2 only and didn't consider #3 until I read it. Who would you say #3 to, a serial killer? No, that w/b *infamous.* Women in the 1700s? IDK. Politicians? Probably not.

Comment: Since *famous* and *a celebrity* are independent here (that's what is being asserted, at least), you need to use *and*, not *but* as a coordinator. *But* requires a level of contrast that is antithetical to the statement being made. It's not a grammar problem, but a pragmatic one.

Comment: I don't think it's asserting that they're independent, just that they're not the same thing. But it's drawing a contrast, which is why "but" is natural.

Answer (score 0):

### No 2 would be the most common reading but No 3 might work in context

For example, imagine you wrote a book under a pseudonym. This book is incredibly successful making the author one of the most famous writers in the world. However, since no one knows who you actually are, you can be famous but you cannot be a celebrity.